# wpf c# sql: can i select table with aggregated values in same stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am *not* using property bindings or collections. I am exporting an Excel file to my DataGrid and simultaneously INSERT into my sql database table using a stored procedure. I aggregate the values of the columns, and add them together in the stored procedure.
The datagrid is populated with pre-calculated data, and the table is filled with POST-calculated data.
But, I want the datagrid to also be populated with the post-calculated data.
I thought I'd just do an easy select * from table after the stored procedure connection had been closed, but i am unable. How can I do this?

My stored procedure looks a bit like this (a bit shortened but):

```
create procedure
as
begin
insert into dbo.myTable(//list of my columns)
    select column1, column2, column3.....
    // do aggregations here

from tblMyTable
end
```

I have tried many things, how can i change this stored procedure to get the table contents after values have been aggregated/calculated

do i need to run a completely new code block in c#. im not sure how to do that with no bindings, and also, i dont want to click a new button, so i hope it can by changing this stored procedure

Comment: *"get the table contents after values have been aggregated/calculated"* what does this mean? `SELECT SUM(SomeColumn)` will return the `SUM` of `SomeColumn`

Comment: How do you call the procedure...?

Comment: Does your stored procedure work correctly and produce the desired effect (which is very unclear) when called directly using a SSMS query window? Generally speaking it is suggested and common for every stored procedure to have "set nocount on;" as the first statement to prevent the return of messages that applications generally don't want and are not prepared to handle.

Comment: @Smor hello yes thank you it sure does. i add excel table with many rows to my datagrid i aggregate and sort and group and i end up wit just 10 lines in the query = as expected. so i was wondering if i could add something like `select * from myTable*  at the end of my stored procedure so that what displays in my datagrid would be updated to the aggregated table and not the old raw data from the excel :( :(

Comment: @mm8 hello there! i have a datatable with string passed in which is openfiledialog selectedfile.

Comment: @hello Larmu, hmmmmm..i try to explain more better.hmmm
i pass in excel sheet datatable to datagrid when i do that my stored procedure also fires off and do calculations and add columns and sort and whatnot. but datagrid does not update , but query shows updated results. what can i do to update datagrid (hopefully with no more buttonclicks) to reflect new values in database?